# How to place Objects in Graphics in front or behind other objects using Inset[] in Mathematica13.3?

Tags: graphics, inset

I made several 2DGraphics using Mathematica v12.0.

To define if an object is placed in front of another or behind, I simply changed the order of the `Inset`. In this case I used
`Graphics[{Inset[ArrowsCyan],Inset[ArrowsBlue]}]` to have the blue arrows in front of the cyan arrows.
[image]

Recently I upgraded to Mathematica 13.3. If I now open the same Notebook, this doesn't work anymore. The cyan arrows are now always in front of the blue ones, independent of the position of `Inset[]`. [image]

Is there an specific command to assign which object should be in front of another?
Or do I have to change something in Mathematica 13.3, or do I have to redo the graphics?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about the use of `Inset` here - could you paste your code? Just changing the order inside `Graphics` works, for example `Graphics[{Cyan, Disk[{1, 1}], Blue, Disk[{1.2, 1.2}]}]` vs `Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{1.2, 1.2}], Cyan, Disk[{1, 1}]}]`